# I can't get mysqli_query to check for existing database values

Tags: php

I have a MySQL table called "Words" with one column called "Word" and several others. I'm inputting an array of words into the function below, trying to check if each exists, and then adding the word if not. Can't quite get it to execute. It keeps throwing up "Couldn't execute query" for however many words are in the array. I've already tested the $sql link connection so I know that's not it. Any suggestions?

`//ADD NEW WORDS TO DATABASE IF THEY DON'T ALREADY EXIST
function addwords($array) {
    foreach($array as $word) {

        $q1 = "SELECT Word FROM Words WHERE Word='$word'";
        $checkWord = mysqli_query($sql, $q1);

        if (!$checkWord) { //IF THERE IS AN ERROR CONNECTING
            echo "Couldn't execute query <br />";
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkWord) > 0) { //IF THE WORD EXISTS
            echo "That word exists, but you should remove this text later.";
            }
        else { //IF THE WORD DOESN'T EXIST
            $q2 = "INSERT INTO Words (Word) VALUES ('$word')";
            mysqli_query($sql, $q2);            
        }
    } //END FOREACH
} //END FUNCTION`

Comment: Where is `$sql` defined in function `addwords`?

Comment: ah, not in the function, .. obviously new to this, and the other instances where it is working it isn't using a function... just reading your variable scope page.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sql` is a global variable. You never define it in your function or use the `global` keyword, so PHP doesn't know about it and your queries fail. You should pass it as a parameter to `function addwords($array)` (make it `function addwords($sql, $array)`).

This is called variable scoping; you should read the [**variable scope page in the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Also, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent someone hosing your database with a value of `$word` like `foo'; DROP TABLE Words --` or simply snooping, with a value like `foo' OR 1=1 --`.

Comment: Thanks!  great advice, I'll give those read.  I guess I should have included this in the code but $sql is the connection variable that's included in another file at the top "include includes/connect.php" It does work like that in some of the other scripts I just wrote.